# insert timestamp to json response in python

Tags: python, json, pubnub

I am trying to insert timestamp to the json curl get request and publish to pubnub  and failing to serialize to right format

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import json
import sys
import datetime
from pubnub import Pubnub

now = datetime.datetime.now()
pubnub = Pubnub(
publish_key = "key",
subscribe_key = "my_key")
channel = "my_channel"

payload = {'Postman-Token': 'sometoken', 'title': "pythontest"}
message = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/",   data=json.dumps(payload))
```

`print.message.text` gives `{"code":"200","message":"Success","itemCount":0,"items":[]}`

I would like to add time stamp to the above message and would like the result to be like this: `{"code":"200","message":"Success",date:"2016-07-31 15:26"}`

```
print now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
timestamp=str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))

print message.text,now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
Hello = str(message.text)

pubnub.publish(
channel = channel,
message = (Hello,timestamp))
```

But, when I publish it to pubnub, the result looks like this.

```
[u'{"code":"200","message":"Success","itemCount":0,"items":[]}', u'2016-07-31 15:26']
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You get this result because you are sending a tuple containing a dictionary and the timestamp, so obviously it will return the tuple as the response. Try to inserting the timestamp in the message you will send.

See if the below works:

```
message = json.loads(requests.get("http://localhost:8080/",   data=json.dumps(payload)))
message["date"] = timestamp
```

It seems to fit for what you want.

Comment: Do you mean like this--->   message = requests.get("http://localhost:8080", data=json.dumps(payload)) timestamp=message["date":now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")]

Comment: Did you try the code I wrote? I didn't really understand what you tried now. Basically once you have message from the request, convert it to a dictionary and use it as such. From there you can do anything.

Comment: I get this error. I am new to python and this is the error I get when I use the code --->  message["date"] = timestamp
NameError: name 'timestamp' is not defined

Comment: This error is because timestamp variable was not declared until this line of code

Comment: I get a different error  now- message["date"] = timestamp
TypeError: 'Response' object does not support item assignment

Comment: did you convert it to a dictionary from json as I suggested? try to see `print type(message)` and check how to convert it to a dictionary.